# Google is complaining that a working URL that is in the sitemap is unreachable

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

I received this warning for a URL that is currently working perfectly. Can you please tell me if this a serious warning, or what it means?

> When we tested a sample of the URLs from your Sitemap, we found that some of the URLs were unreachable. Please check your webserver for possible misconfiguration, as these errors may be caused by a server error (such as a 5xx error) or a network error between Googlebot and your server. All reachable URLs will still be submitted.

Comment: Are those pages was not working in past? I mean Google search console is not real time, so they might show one/two day old errors. If those errors are fixed then you should not worry about it. To make sure, put your working URL's on [fetch and render tool from search console](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en), and see how Google currently view your webpages.

Comment: Make sure that the URLs within your sitemap are working and correct. If you are reasonably sure that all is truly well with your sitemap, then please consider that the term *unreachable* can be almost anything including a network error somewhere between Google and your site. This is not uncommon. Otherwise, also look for 404 and 500 errors in Googles Search Console and/or log file analyzer. If you see an increase, then you may really have a problem. If not? Then it is more likely that Google could not reach your site at all for some reason that may be beyond your control. Cheers!!

Comment: ya urls and sitemap are working correctly

Answer (score 1):

Test your pages with different user agents, different languages, with browser, which doesn't accept cookies and doesn't use javascript. On this way you'll find pages, which aren't available for googlebot.

It often happens, that pages, which are available from usual browser (answer code 200), are not available (redirected or fire server error) under specific circumstances.

You can easily automate such tests using Screaming Frog or using some browser extensions, if there are only few pages to test.

It helps to inspect your server configuration (like htaccess file for Apache) and, if in use, an engine which recognizes mobile user agents and redirects mobile users to specific pages or page variants. Wrong configuration of such engines is often an error source too.